# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonBarButtonStyle'

Tags: android, styles, themes

I write a theme in styles.xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <!-- Root styles that vary by API level -->
<style name="FrameworkRoot.Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 11+ (compatibility) -->
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/Compat.ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Compat.ButtonBarButton</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Compat.IndeterminateProgress</item>
    <!-- API 14+ (compatibility) -->
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_left</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_right</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_height_small</item>
</style>
```

but get the error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonBarStyle'.

I get the code from the google io2012. Both mine and its'  all base

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I can compile the google io2012's source code but not mine. so strange.
is anybody know why? or have the same question?

Comment: In my opinion you need compat.xml and attrs.xml in ../res/values folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`buttonBarStyle` is for versions 11 and above as you state in your SDK but you are using `android:minSdkVersion="8"`. Isn't it supposed to work for `android:minSdkVersion="11"`?

Comment: when I change the minSdkVersion="8", and clean the project, the error still exists.

Comment: by the way, the google io 2012's code can run with android:minSdkVersion="8" . I think I miss something Configuration

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem... I have two projects in my Eclipse workspace, both based on the Android 4.2 jar.  One has minSdkVersion="8" with targetSdkVersion="17" and its style references both the `buttonBarStyle` and `buttonBarButtonStyle` names just fine.  The other project uses the same manifest settings and will not build due to the errors:

```
 No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonBarStyle'.
 No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'buttonBarButtonStyle'.
```

When I saw `@dead's` comment about needing an `attrs.xml` file, I checked and sure enough, the project that wouldn't compile was missing this file.  I think the working project was generated using the Eclipse Android Application Project wizard, while the other was created manually.

The contents of `res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <!--
         Declare custom theme attributes that allow changing which styles are
         used for button bars depending on the API level.
         ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle is new as of API 11 so this is
         necessary to support previous API levels.
    -->
    <declare-styleable name="ButtonBarContainerTheme">
        <attr name="buttonBarStyle" format="reference" />
        <attr name="buttonBarButtonStyle" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

The contents of `res/values/colors.xml:`

```
<resources>

    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>

</resources>
```

And the three style files:

1) res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level 
             can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />

    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item> 
        <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ContentText">
        <item name="android:textColor">#0000ff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">50sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

2) res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

3) res/values-v14/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you - this also taught me a bit more about themes in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below link. Add the values which are used in your code and delete the rest .
Hope it helps you.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the AppCompat . It is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Check the topic Adding libraries with resources.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as yours:

my `build.gradle`file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.whatever"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
```

what I did in my Values folder added a `attrs.XML` file, with this codes in it:

```
<declare-styleable name="ButtonBarContainerTheme">
    <attr name="metaButtonBarStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

now I see no complains!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error....deleted the folders at

C:\Users\.android\build-cache\Hash Number of Folders E.g. 4eaccf0d162ec009b115c7e0ff4f542f8d2a663b\

and it worked like a charm....