# Got an error while building a project in new workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

Am new for android development. I tried to create a new workspace with **Target SDK as API 21 and Compiled with API 19**. I have installed the sdk of **API19 and 20 and not the Android5**. I created a new workspace and created a new project in which I ended up with the below error while compiling the project after creating it. Can anyone help me how to get rid of this?

Error details:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Error: No resource
>   found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v11    line
>   352   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v11    line
>   345   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v11    line
>   359   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v11    line
>   338   Android AAPT Problem The project cannot be built until build path
>   errors are resolved   SampleApp       Unknown Java Problem error: Error: No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   193   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlHighlight'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   195   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   191   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimary'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   190   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   174   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   93    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   168   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   172   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   97    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   101   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   121   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   107   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:overlapAnchor'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   138   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   126   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   202   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   62    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   113   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material'.    styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   20    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   182   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   110   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   115   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   223   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   154   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   26    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   219   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   150   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   28    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   205   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   22    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   164   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   212   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   158   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   24    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.    styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   34    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   129   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   82    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:overlapAnchor'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   143   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   36    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlHighlight'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   84    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   146   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   30    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   83    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   32    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   132   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   81    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   60    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   29    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   118   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   33    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.   styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   42    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   120   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.    styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   40    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   37    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimary'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   79    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   38    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   41    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   80    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   52    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.   styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   75    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimary'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   116   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   79    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   50    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   117   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   48    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   83    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlHighlight'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   121   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   25    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.    styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   46    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   119   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   53    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlHighlight'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   158   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   57    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   58    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   156   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.  styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   56    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   61    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   155   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'. styles_base_text.xml    /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   54    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   178   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   157   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.    styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   65    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   192   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   69    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   194   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   45    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimary'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   153   Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   154   Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'. styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   49    Android AAPT Problem The container 'Android Dependencies'
>   references non existing library
>   'D:\Workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'  SampleApp       Build
>   path  Build Path Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v14    line
>   37    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v14    line
>   29    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v14    line
>   53    Android AAPT Problem error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v14    line
>   45    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Theme.Material'. themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   26    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Theme.Material.Light'.   themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   31    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.  themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   36    Android AAPT Problem error: Error retrieving parent for item: No
>   resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.    themes_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21    line
>   41    Android AAPT Problem

Answer (score 21):

1. Update the project.properties file of **appcompat v7**, which has:`target=android-19` to `target=android-21`
2. Also update `google play services` library (by `update` I mean update it in `SDK Manager` and re-import etc)

Comment: #1 Fixed the issue for me.  The appcompat_v7 project was targeted at 4.4.2 so it failed to link the v21 libs.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 16):

Right click project properties and change project Build Target To 5.0

[image]

change target=android-21 in your manifest

Comment: And then clean the project.

Comment: Even, I am still having the same error after doing this

Comment: If you choose Google API's , Check your  Sdk(sdk manager ) is Google api  installed or not ?

Answer (score 3):

compile project with Android 5.0 API leveL 21.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug.

I just verified that I can create a new Hello World app ( the standard default ) just fine with Version 20 of Android Support Library ( using SDK all the way down to 14 ).  However, it fails with 21.0.3 with the exact same errors that you posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error as someone new to installing Android tools and having mistakenly selected the 4.4W as well as 4.4.2 in the Android SDK Manager.

This results in having both API 20 and API 19 installed which means API 20 seems to be newer and will be picked up by default for new projects.

However, **API 20 is Wearables Only.**

You can see here in [image: screenshot of Navigator Properties] that 4.4W has ended up in the path.

Both the appcompat_v7 and HelloAndy project targets had this path problem.

I edited project.properties for both and changed target=android-20 to target=android-19 then did a Refresh on both projects (right-click the appcompat_v7 and other project). That updated the build paths to point to the correct Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the project's build target to Android 4.4.2 too?

Here guys had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843198/3864698

Answer (score 0):

One anther thing you can try is to open the project.properties file of the android-support-v7-appcompat and change the target target. And then just do a Project --> Clean so that the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compiled with` setting should be the same or later than your `target` setting. If you try to target api 21 with tools that don't understand api 21, you shouldn't be surprised when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the workspace and definitely your error will be rectified.

There is some bug in android app v7 library.

Create a new workspace and then create a project. Use the same steps and you will not find an error this time.

Comment: The eclipse workspace has nohing to do with project compilation. Look at the debug lines...its only lines in V21 that have issues implying you need to compile with at least android-21. Changing workspaces has no effect on issue, it just means you have a dirty /bin directory in your project which can be cleaned with project->clean

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and tried all the solutions provided on stackoverflow, but non of them worked for me. Finally I came across this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33505965/3840615

and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove that style line whereever error is found then clean your project

and make your project 5.0 setted