# Unable to resolve target 'android-21'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have the latest ADT plugin for eclipse: **ADT-23.0.4**.
Eclipse Version: **Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)**.

Still I am getting this error while importing a project:

> *Unable to resolve target 'android-21'*

Comment: check with this  2  answers : [Answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623083/got-an-error-while-building-a-project-in-new-workspace/26993815#26993815)  [Answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989567/android-eclipse-importing-old-project-shows-error-on-android-l-5-0)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73415

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right Click on `Project -> Properties -> android` -> choose your target api level you have,
Then press Apply and Ok

And clean the project once and rebuild it.

Comment: tried it.....got these errors: "The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured."   "You must restart adb and Eclipse."   and   "Please ensure that adb is correctly located at *D:\..\adb.exe*"

Answer (score 7):

Go to `Windows -> Android SDK Manager` Install the Android API Level you want, in this case 21.

Once you've finished installing, go to `Window -> Preference -> Android`. You should get a list of available targets. Click **Apply** then **Ok**.

Now right click your project, go to properties. Click Android. Choose your desired target.

Comment: While tried checking for updates: No repository found at file:/D:/../android-sdk-windows/.

Comment: This usually occurs for eclipse IDE. Is it eclipse classic or something? You can change eclipse.

Comment: It's eclipse luna 4.4.1